# C++: Debugging C++ Template Linker Errors

Tags: c++, debugging, templates, linker, linker-errors

I got a strange linker error on the following code:

The code uses type traits to provide a partial template specialization for all types `A<T>` where `T` is not a subtype of `X`.

```
class X{};

#include <type_traits>

//Enabler for all types that are not a subtype of X
#define enabler(T) typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<X, T>::value>::type


//A template (second param is only for enabling partial specializations)
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct A{};

//Partial template specialization for instances
//that do not use a T which is a subclass of X
template <typename T>
struct A<T, enabler(T)>{
    static int foo(); //Declaration only!
};

//Definition of foo() for the partial specialization
template <typename T,enabler(T)>
static int foo(){
    return 4;
}

int bar = A<int>::foo();

int main(){}
```

Even though this is only one file, linking fails. The problem seems to be the non-inline definition of foo(). Once I inline it, everything works fine. In the real code, I cannot inline it due to circular dependencies.

The error is the following:

```
/tmp/ccS7UIez.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
X.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `A<int, void>::foo()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe it's a slightly wrong type, like a const missing? Or there's a namespace involved...

Comment: Your "Definition" is wrong, think of what it should be like without the `enable_if` stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of static member function `A<T, enabler(T)>::foo` has syntax errors, should be :

```
template <typename T>
int A<T, enabler(T)>::foo(){
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: when I use your version, I receive the following compiler error: `X.cpp:23:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_base_of<X, T>::value), void>::type>’
X.cpp:12:9: error: declaration of ‘struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_base_of<X, T>::value), void>::type>’`